# heroku PostgreSQL db migration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm getting error when I try to migrate postgres database in heroku.
First I got:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate --trace
rake aborted!
undefined method `find_by_name' for Gem::Specification:Class
/app/lib/tasks/auto_annotate_models.rake:22:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/depen                                        dencies.rb:245:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/depen                                        dencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/depen                                        dencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/depen                                        dencies.rb:245:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `b                                        lock in load_tasks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `e                                        ach'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `l                                        oad_tasks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:145:                                        in `load_tasks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurabl                                        e.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/app/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `lo                                        ad'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `lo                                        ad_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:583:in `r                                        aw_load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `bl                                        ock in load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `s                                        tandard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `lo                                        ad_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `bl                                        ock in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `s                                        tandard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `ru                                        n'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

What's going on?

Comment: I think you should post your Gemfile. Hard to say what's wrong and I don't get this bit: "Then I added ruby "1.9.3" in Gemfile and then I got"

Comment: holy wall-of-text batman!

Comment: I don't think `find_by_name` or any `find_by_xxxxx` is supported by default anymore... is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you do heroku run rake db:create before you do your migrate?

Comment: Tried that but didn't help. 

Found the issue later. it's a script from annotate gem, not sure if that was the old script or someone else added it in the project I'm working on. I've removed the script and it's now working. Thx.